# Ansible - Loop over nested array inside list of objects?

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to find the most efficient way to install every PHP version and packages for each version without duplication.

I currently have this:

```
- name: Install PHP
  apt:
    name: "{{ packages.php_version }}-{{ packages.packages }}"
  vars:
    packages:
      - { php_version: 5.6, packages: ['common', 'cli', 'opcache', 'mysql', 'mbstring', 'simplexml', 'curl', 'bcmath', 'ldap', 'gd', 'dom', 'zip', 'xml', 'readline', 'json', 'fpm', 'imagick']}
      - { php_version: 7.0, packages: ['common', 'cli', 'opcache', 'mysql', 'mbstring', 'simplexml', 'curl', 'bcmath', 'ldap', 'gd', 'dom', 'zip', 'xml', 'readline', 'json', 'fpm', 'imagick']}
```

However, i cannot workout the selector to itterate over the packages.

I would like to have something where it basically loops over each php version and the packages for each, as they may be different.

Thanks

**EDIT TO ANSWER**
Pretty much there for me! Thanks so much. I wanted to install *all* the PHP versions just just a selected one. So i did the following:

```
- name: Install PHP
  apt:
    name: "php{{ item.0.key }}-{{ item.1 }}"
  loop: "{{ packages_dict | dict2items | subelements('value') }}"
```

Not sure if thats the best way? seems inefficient really but it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most efficient way would be converting the list to a dictionary first. For example

```yaml
  packages_dict: "{{ packages|items2dict(key_name='php_version',
                                         value_name='packages') }}"
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  packages_dict:
    '5.6':
    - common
    - cli
    - opcache
    '7.0':
    - common
    - cli
    - opcache
```

Then the selection and iteration is trivial, e.g.

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    packages:
      - php_version: '5.6'
        packages: ['common', 'cli', 'opcache']
      - php_version: '7.0'
        packages: ['common', 'cli', 'opcache']
    packages_dict: "{{ packages|items2dict(key_name='php_version',
                                           value_name='packages') }}"
    php_version: "{{ my_php_version|d('5.6') }}"
  tasks:
    - name: Install PHP
      debug:
        msg: "name: {{ php_version }}-{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ packages_dict[php_version] }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: 'name: 5.6-common'
  msg: 'name: 5.6-cli'
  msg: 'name: 5.6-opcache'
```

---

Q: *"**I wanted to install ALL php versions.**"*

A: No conversion is needed in this case. You can iterate the list *packages* with *subelements*, .e.g

```yaml
    - name: Install PHP
      debug:
        msg: "name: {{ item.0.php_version }}-{{ item.1 }}"
      with_subelements:
        - "{{ packages }}"
        - packages
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: 'name: 5.6-common'
  msg: 'name: 5.6-cli'
  msg: 'name: 5.6-opcache'
  msg: 'name: 7.0-common'
  msg: 'name: 7.0-cli'
  msg: 'name: 7.0-opcache'
```

Comment: See edit on original post, markdown wasn't working in this comment. Thanks so much for pointing me in the right direction. However, i wanted to install ALL php versions not just a selected one.